# 502 Bad Gateway nginx, I have one dominion for two distinct apps (FLASK and DJANGO). I'm using one index page to distribute routes

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

**I think this erros happens, because of proxy_pass is incorrect, if someone has any idea please tell me thanks**

> NGINX FILE

```
proxy_cache_path /var/nginx/cache/project
keys_zone=djangoproject_cache:60m;

gzip on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types text/plain text/xml text/css application/javascript application/x-javascript;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_disable msie6;

upstream appserver {
        server unix:/home/dir/projects/djangoproject/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {

    listen 443;
    server_name www.subdominion.dominion www.subdominion.dominion;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";

    ssl_certificate    certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key        certificate.key;

    ssl on;
    server_tokens off;

    root /var/www/html/;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }


    location /djangoproject{

      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      # Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
      rewrite ^/djangoproject(.*) /$1 break;
      proxy_pass          http://unix:/home/sftpserver/projects/podaexpress/gunicorn.sock; -- I think the error is here
      try_files $uri @proxy_to_appserver;
      access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
      error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
      sendfile_max_chunk 1024k;
      root /home/dir/projects/djangoproject/static;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;
    }

    location /flaskproject{
      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      # Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
      rewrite ^/flaskproject(.*) /$1 break;

      proxy_pass          http://unix:/home/dir/projects/flaskproject/gunicorn.sock;

      proxy_read_timeout  90;

    }

    location @proxy_to_appserver {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
        proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_pass http://appserver;
    }
}
```

*using this nginx file I got one page manager index.html, in this page has two buttons with href link for my dominion/djangoproject or dominion/flaskproject , everything is correct until here, but when I click in button whose link directs for another project has one error http 502, but gunicorn file is correct*

> gunicorn file from djangoproject

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="djangoproject"                                              # Name of the application (*)
DJANGODIR=/home/dir/projects/djangoproject/                # Django project directory (*)
SOCKFILE=/home/dir/projects/djangoproject/gunicorn.sock    # we will communicate using this unix socket (*)
USER=root                                                       # the user to run as (*)
GROUP=root                                                      # the group to run as (*)
NUM_WORKERS=15                                                  # how many worker processes should Gunicorn spawn (*)
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.qasettings                      # which settings file should Django use (*)
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=project.wsgi                                  # WSGI module name (*)

echo "------------- INICIANDO $NAME gunicorn -------------"

# Activate the virtual environment
cd $DJANGODIR
source /home/dir/projects/djangoproject/bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist
RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

# Start your Django Unicorn Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves (do not use --daemon)
exec /home/dir/projects/djangoproject/bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user $USER \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
  --daemon
```

*in both links I get the correct url example https://subdominion.dominion.com.br/djangoprojects or https://subdominion.dominion.com.br/flaskproject*

Comment: What is in your nginx error.log ?

Comment: The error was mine, my gunicorn file was not creating .sock file, but now I need add static files in my nginx file and I don't know how, because I using a reverse proxy rsrsrs.

Comment: @JosefKorbel  could you help me on this?

Comment: Static files from Flask or Django? Or both?

Comment: I already did the django, miss the flask

Comment: That is pretty similiar, you can just add a location to your nginx config like location /static { root /path/to/my/static/files }